# Running a timed background job in bash

Tags: bash, job-control, watch

I would like to execute a command in bash every 30 seconds and have it run as a background job. Form [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82616/how-to-execute-command-every-10-seconds-without-cron), I gather that using the watch command is useful. However every time I attempt to background it, it stops.

> `watch -n 1 'date >> dateFile.txt'`

works. I can `cat dateFilet.txt` and see a bunch of lines.

> `watch -n 1 'date >> dateFile.txt' &`

returns

> `[1]+  Stopped                 watch -n 1 'date >> dateFile.txt'`

executing `bg` returns the same line again.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it? What I eventually want to do is source a file every minute or so to keep certain variables in my bash session up to date.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify that you need to source a file. That has a whole set of problems of its own and the valid solutions for your `date` example will not work. I would remove the `date` altogether and make the question specifically about sourcing variable definitions from a file every few seconds.

Comment: `watch` is [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) based and doesn't have a daemon option.  I'd say it's clearly not intended for this purpose (perhaps because doing this with the shell is simple enough, see sputnick's `while true` suggestion -- except what you actually want to do here is a complication as per terdon's comment).

Comment: You don't want to *source a file* to keep vars up to date - and you especially do not want to do that every thirty seconds. That's what the prompt does. Put the definitions in there. That's it's job.

Comment: @mikeserv that's a clever trick and deserves being made into an answer. It's probably the only way the OP can do what they want.

Comment: @terdon - it's no trick - that's really any prompt's primary purpose. It provides constantly re-evaluated variable information. Not all of it has to be *printed* every time...

Comment: @mikeserv yes but it is also _the_ answer and I doubt the OP will be able to understand our exchange. It will be pretty cryptic to someone unaware of `PS1` or bash's `$PROMPT_COMMAND`. Why not expand it into an answer?

Comment: @terdon - because I have no idea what the asker wants to define. I'm not going to detail exactly how he/she can easily accidentally overwrite `$PATH` every time he/she presses *return*... I'd rather the asker either asked a new, more specific question, or made this one more clear. I think the answers to this one have already been had, though.

Comment: @terdon - I was hoping to even run scripts that way apart from just sourcing files. Moreover, I am going to be running a script to generate the updated vars anyhow. I'll see what I can do to clarify the question.

Comment: @LordLoh. running scripts might be possible, depends on the script. Sputnick's answer shows how to do that. Sourcing is more complex and you'd need to do what mikeserv suggested and I explained in my answer. This is turning into a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to specify what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

In bash, you can do this easily using the [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) variable (from `man bash`):

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>
> If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each
>                 primary prompt.

So, if you add something like this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=". /path/to/file"
```

You will have any variables defined in that file available.

Answer (score 3):

In your `crontab` :

```
* * * * * date >> dateFile.txt & sleep 30; date >> dateFile.txt &
```

Straightforward, no ? =)

(Better put the full PATH of the `date` command)

Another solution:

```
while true; do date >> dateFile.txt & sleep 30; done
```

Comment: These are both reasonable suggestions but neither will help the OP source a file and have the variables sourced available in their current shell session.

Comment: The OP question is not that clear, I use the own OP example command

Comment: Your answer is a good one (+1) WRT most of the question.  The qualifier ("I want to source environment variables into my current shell via a background process") is not possible anyway.

Comment: Absolutely, I'm not saying it's your fault. That's why I also [asked the OP](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166187/running-a-timed-background-job-in-bash#comment273148_166187) to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

> What I eventually want to do is source a file every minute or so to keep certain variables in my bash session up to date.

- You **cannot** do that from a child process.
- You **cannot** do that from a parent process.
- You **cannot** do that from any process other than the one you want it to affect.

Changing a process's environment is the same as changing a process's private memory (in fact, that's exactly what would be involved).  Absolutely not allowed!  That's why [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) is such an elaborate realm.